# Not able to record human action while using desktop application on linux using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, linux

I have a GIS related desktop application on RHEL which communicates to server for fetching and posting data. I  am trying to use Jmeter for recording the human actions, I changed the proxy settings of the Linux machine also so that tool could capture traffic but recorder is not able to record anything. Changed configurations are below:

1. port Used in Jmeter is 8888, same port is set in network settings of Linux machine.
2. IP changed to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or the system's ip.

What else needs to be done or other way has to used...Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case your application doesn't respect system-wide proxy settings and it either has its own separate proxy configuration like i.e. [Firefox browser](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox) does or respects [`http_proxy` environment variable](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/set-up-proxy-http-proxy-environment-variable/) instead
2. In case of HTTPS traffic you need to [import JMeter's MITM certificate into your RHEL trust store](https://blog.confirm.ch/adding-a-new-trusted-certificate-authority/)
3. As it evidenced by its name JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder can only record HTTP or HTTPS traffic, if your application uses different protocol(s) you will need to use a sniffer tool like [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) and then look for suitable [JMeter Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) or [JMeter Plugins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager) which support this(ese) protocol(s)